# Eclipse like console in Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am going to do some code in c# using visual studio 2010. The problem is that every time I run program it does appear in command prompt.

I would like place the output of the program in the console like in the Eclipse. `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("abc");` this does not work cause if I look at the output I see much more information than I want. *I would like to see only data which would show in the command prompt*.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand.. but isn't `Console.Write()` what you're after..?

Comment: Console.Write() runs in the external console, I want it to be showed in the internal Visual Studio Console I don't want any external console turning on when program is run.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Tools->Options->Debug->Output Window" - you should be able to decrease amount of traces to your liking.

Side note: normally "output of program" means results of Console.WriteXXXX methods, so maybe you are looking for something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to turn off verbose Output logging so that only your `Debug.Write's` will be written to the output window.

To do this you goto Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > and turn off the verbose logging:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to running command prompt output inside the visual studio?

Comment: If you are running a Console application the output from `Console.Write` will be shown in the Console applications command prompt window. If you are running a standard cmd windows I dont think you can output to VS without a lot of work. It would be simple to port info to a text file from a command prompt. eg Here's a command that prints out the directory tree into a text file. `Tree > C:\Tree.txt`. Where **tree** is the dos command and `> c:\a.txt` is the syntax to port the results out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all of your output, you can redirect your Debug.Print to output to the Immediate Window instead.

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General | Click on Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window.

This does not mean everything will be outputted to it, just the output that you designate in your code and any exception messages that get thrown. It's a lot less chatty and still keeps your Output window with all the standard messages.